# Why don't Stat Commands work on elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I'm trying to find when I installed elementary Os on my laptop
I've tried:

```
stat / | grep "Birth" | sed 's/Birth: //g' | cut -b 2-11
```

- 

but only a - appears
no mistake messages, just the -

Answer (score 0):

How about you try `stat --printf="%w" / | cut -b 1-10` ?

I'm thinking it might be a case where the birth time field is not always available and may not be displayed for all files. In this case, the stat command will output a dash (-) instead of the birth time.

Comment: same result with "stat --printf="%w" / | cut -b 1-10",  the only  output is a dash (-)